# How to transform data in one cell to multiple rows while keeping the rest of the columns constant?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to split words from one cell into multiple rows while keeping the information in other cells the same. Basically making my data long-format.

Is this possible with excel?

In the example image I would like to split the Theme column into separate rows but keeping the correct information in the Country column. How could I do this?

Example :

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do it on your example sheet:

- In your example sheet select the data (A2:B8)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to convert the selection into a table
- Click in pane Data then *Get Data > From Table/Range* to open the
  Power Query Editor
- Select the second column by clicking its header
- Click in pane Transform then *Split Column > By Delimiter*
- In the dialog, the separator should already be selected as `;`
- Click *Advanced options > Split into > Rows*
- Click OK and preview the changes
- Click Close and Load to create a new worksheet with the new data.
- Instead of the last step, you may also select the new data by clicking
  the headers (use <kbd>Shift</kbd> for the second one) and copy the data with
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you! This did it!

Comment: you are my god!

Comment: What a legendary answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with formulae, as long as there is always the same amount of themes to split. On a new sheet we will unwrap the source data:

The header in Sheet2!A1 (and copy to B1):

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

In the rest of column A2 and onwards:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10000, INT((ROW()-2)/3)+1)
```

In B2 and onwards:

```
=LET(theme, INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10000, INT((ROW()-2)/3)+1), sep_1, FIND("; ", theme), sep_2, FIND("; ", theme, sep_1+1), sep_3, LEN(theme), CHOOSE(MOD(ROW()-2,3)+1, LEFT(theme, sep_1-1), MID(theme, sep_1+1, sep_2-sep_1-1), RIGHT(theme, sep_3-sep_2)))
```

If you don't have LET (i.e. Excel 365), you might have to put each of the LET variables in its own helper column, then hide the helper column.

The basic working of this formula is to use INT((ROW()-2)/3)+1 to map row numbers {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7...} to {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2...} for referring to the source row number country and theme. Then use MOD(...) to map rows {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7...} to {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3...} to indicate which theme in the list to extract, i.e. we use CHOOSE(*mapped row 1, 2 or 3*, *first text*, *second text*, *third text*). The sep_# LET variables help locate each "; " seperator in the theme text.